# create a log from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I have a batch file (.BAT) and would like to capture its output into a file automatically every time it is run.  I know I can use redirection but then I wouldn't be able to watch it as it's running.  Also, other people use this batch file and I want the log to be created without the user having to do anything special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tee for windows? http://www.chipstips.com/?p=129

Comment: Is there any way to use "tee" without making the user type it (meaning: they just run my batch file and the batch file somehow calls "tee" automatically)

Comment: @JoelFan: Yes, there is a simple way: Use another batch file (or the same batch file calling itself with different options).

Answer (score 2):

If you're adverse to downloading or installing `tee` you can use a simple subroutine to emulate it:

```
rem log <message>
:log
echo.%*
1>>logfile.txt echo.%*
```

and then just output by using `call :log Some crazy message`. This will only work for your own messages, however, it doesn't do anything with programs you run from your batch. You could probably do that by introducing another subroutine:

```
rem runlog <program> <arguments>
:runlog
setlocal
set FN=%RANDOM%
1>%FN%.tmp 2>&1 %*
type %FN%.tmp
1>>logfile.txt type %FN%.tmp
del %FN%.tmp
endlocal
```